# getting css attributes before the containing div is toggled

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I've made a user control containing a panel, which is being loaded in a page, being toggled. in the js of that userControl i have a function in my document.ready that needs those attributes such as height, width, position, z-index. but those are all set to 0 cause the whole containing div is'nt yet toggled.
what should i do to have those attributes before the toggling?
thanx in advance.

Comment: I think we are going to need to see some code to know what you are doing.

Comment: $(window).load(function () {
  var element = $('div[id*="pnl2"]');
  for (i = 0; i <= element.length; i++) {
   showoverlay(element[i], false, false);
  } 
 })function showoverlay(elm, enableFlag, isBetween) {
  if ($(elm).height() != null) {
   var h = $(elm).height();
   var position = $(elm).position();
   var top = 0 - h;
   var heightB = h / 2;
   var topB = top + heightB;
   var left = position.left;
   var w = $(elm).width();
   
   $(elm).append('<div></div>');
   var e = $(elm).children(':last');
   $(e).css({ 'height': h, 'top': top});
   }

  }

Answer (score 1):

If those attributes aren't explicitly set, they probably are going to show up zero if you access them directly.  Use a JQuery method like outerHeight and outerWidth to get the dimensions.  Also, set up the initial values in document.ready event too.

HTH.

Comment: dear Brian! outerHeight didnt work. and I have already put the function in both document.ready and window.load, neither would seem to work.